# Why is Task.IsCanceled Not True?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have a simple program here

```
private static void CancellingSingleTask()
{
    DateTime whenStarted = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: Started", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        int? taskId = Task.CurrentId;

        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Task - [{1}]:  Started", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks), taskId);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Task - [{1}]:  Cancellation Requested", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks), taskId);
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Task - [{1}]:  No Cancellation Requested", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks), taskId);
    }, ct);

    Action Print = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: Task.IsCanceled = [{1}]  Task.IsFaulted = [{2}] Task.IsCompleted = [{3}] Task.Status = [{4}]", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks),
            task.IsCanceled, task.IsFaulted, task.IsCompleted, task.Status);
    };

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: Started New Task", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));
    Print();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: Cancelling Task", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));

    cts.Cancel();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: After Cancelling Task", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));
    Print();

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: Waiting For Task", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));

        task.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: After Waiting For Task", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));
        Print();
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: In Catch Block", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks));
        Print();

        foreach (var exception in aggregateException.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Main: Received Exception In Task [{1}]", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks), exception.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

**Sample Output**
    [00:00:00.0010000] - Main: Started
    [00:00:00.0040002] - Main: Started New Task
    [00:00:00.0060003] - Main: IsCanceled = [False]  IsFaulted = [False] IsCompleted = [False] Status = [Running]
    [00:00:00.0070004] - Task - [1]:  Started
    [00:00:01.0070576] - Main: Cancelling Task
    [00:00:02.0071148] - Task - [1]:  Cancellation Requested
    [00:00:03.0111722] - Main: After Cancelling Task
    [00:00:03.0111722] - Main: IsCanceled = [False]  IsFaulted = [True] IsCompleted = [True] Status =     [Faulted]
    [00:00:03.0111722] - Main: Waiting For Task
    [00:00:05.0112866] - Main: In Catch Block
    [00:00:05.0112866] - Main: IsCanceled = [False]  IsFaulted = [True] IsCompleted = [True] Status = [Faulted]
    [00:00:05.0112866] - Main: Received Exception In Task [The operation was canceled.]

I never see the Task.IsCanceled Set to true, am I making a mistake or missing something obvious.
I have done a bit of research/searching on this issue but was not able to find a conclusive answer.

Note: Related Questions on StackOverFlow
[Cancellation of a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896269/cancellation-of-a-task/13896417#13896417) [task IsCanceled is false, while I canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738008/task-iscanceled-is-false-while-i-canceled) [Task.IsCancelled doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384237/task-iscancelled-doesnt-work)

Comment: `throw new OperationCanceledException(ct);`? or `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` ?

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you should pass the `CancellationToken` to the constructor of `OperationCanceledException`.

```
  if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Task - [{1}]:  Cancellation Requested", TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - whenStarted.Ticks), taskId);
        throw new OperationCanceledException(ct);
    }
```

TPL will check whether both `CancellationToken` are same, if so it will mark task as `Cancelled` in your case it is not and so TPL assumes your task is not cancelled.

or even better use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method, as simple as that

```
ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Comment: So its a two way process than, after the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` the task should explicitly acknowledge the cancellation via the `CancellationToken`, Throwing a `OperationCanceledException` is not sufficient. This clears a lot of things. Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course and that's why microsoft calls this pattern as *cooperative cancellation*. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) out, read first two bullet points that explains the thing :)